# ASP.NET - Dealing with dependencies when using the debugger

Tags: asp.net

When we run ASP.NET through the debugger it runs in a special directory like:

> C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0

I dont know if this directory is configureable.  The problem is that if you have a file such as `Transfer.xsl` then you set its property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".  This copies the file out to the bin.

But, we are not running inside the bin.  So if I use a relative path

StorageFolder\Transfer.xsl

It becomes...

> C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\StorageFolder\Transfer.xsl

But, Visual Studio does **not** copy files here even when you set the property described above.

In the past I got around this problem by writing a pre-build routine to xcopy the dependencies to this "temp folder".  It works, but flippen sucks caseadillas.

Is there a better way?

Comment: It sounds like you're using the wrong context for file operations; in ASP.NET, you should use `this.Page.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET application you could use the `App_Data` special folder to store files. And when you want to get the full path to this file you use the `MapPath` method:

```
string fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Transfer.xsl");
```